# How to index a datetime column from imported csv file - pandas

Tags: csv, datetime, pandas, indexing, concatenation

I am trying to merge & append different timeseries, importing them from csv files. I have tried the following basic code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import glob
import csv
import os

path = r'./A08_csv'     # use your path
#all_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(path, "A08_B1_T5.csv"))

df5 = pd.read_csv('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T5.csv', parse_dates={'Date Time'})
df6 = pd.read_csv('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T6.csv', parse_dates={'Date Time'})

print len(df5)
print len(df6)

df = pd.concat([df5],[df6], join='outer')
print len(df)
```

and the result is:

```
12755 (df5)
24770 (df6)
12755 (df)
```

Shouldn't df as long as the longest of the two files (which have lots of rows in common, in terms of values on ['Date Time'] column)??

I have tried to index the data based on datetime, adding this line:

```
#df5.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df5['Date Time']))
```

However I received the error:

```
KeyError: 'Date Time'
```

Any clue on why this happens?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think you need:

```
df5.set_index(['Date Time'], inplace=True)
```

Or better in [`read_csv`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.read_csv.html) add parameter `index_col`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

temp=u"""Date Time,a
2010-01-27 16:00:00,2.0
2010-01-27 16:10:00,2.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00,1.7"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=['Date Time'], parse_dates=['Date Time'])
print (df)
                       a
Date Time               
2010-01-27 16:00:00  2.0
2010-01-27 16:10:00  2.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00  1.7

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-27 16:00:00', '2010-01-27 16:10:00',
               '2010-01-27 16:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date Time', freq=None)
```

Another solution is add to paramaters column by order - if column `Date Time` is first, add `0` to `index_col` and `parse_dates` (python count from `0`):

```
import pandas as pd
import io


temp=u"""Date Time,a
2010-01-27 16:00:00,2.0
2010-01-27 16:10:00,2.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00,1.7"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(temp), index_col=0, parse_dates=[0])
print (df)
                       a
Date Time               
2010-01-27 16:00:00  2.0
2010-01-27 16:10:00  2.2
2010-01-27 16:30:00  1.7

print (df.index)
DatetimeIndex(['2010-01-27 16:00:00', '2010-01-27 16:10:00',
               '2010-01-27 16:30:00'],
              dtype='datetime64[ns]', name='Date Time', freq=None)
```

Comment: Thanks.
the code `df5 = pd.read_csv('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T5.csv', index_col=['Date Time'], parse_dates=['Date Time'])` returns `ValueError: 'Date Time' is not in list`

Comment: Do you need still set index to from column `Date Time`? Or now it is not necessary?

Comment: If need it, what is after `df5 = pd.read_csv('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T5.csv', parse_dates=['Date Time'])` `print df.dtypes` ?

Comment: Yes, I need it as it seems that otherwise the pd.concat (as per above) would not work (plus I would need to resample and calculate means etc ).
Why does that not work??

Comment: Can you answer for my last comment? What is `print df.dtypes` ?

Comment: jezrael, I had to change the code to `df5 = pd.read_csv('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T5.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])
df6 = pd.read_csv('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T6.csv', index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0])` as it would not accept `['Date Time']` neither for parse_dates, nor for index_col

print df5.dtypes returns `Temp (°C) LGR S/N: 10593597 c:1    float64
RH (%) LGR S/N: 10593597 c:2       float64
dtype: object`

Comment: `Date Time` is first column in `csv`? what says `print df.index` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/116599/discussion-between-andreuccio-and-jezrael).

Answer (score 0):

This is incorrect:

```
pd.concat([df5],[df6], join='outer')
```

The second argument to `concat` is the `axis`. Instead, you want:

```
pd.concat([df5, df6], join='outer')
```