# Merge/concatenate CSV-imported dataframes and delete duplicates

Tags: loops, csv, pandas, duplicates

I am following up on my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38230642/how-to-index-a-datetime-column-from-imported-csv-file-pandas/38230735?noredirect=1#comment63884154_38230735).

Have sorted out a loop to import CSVs, concatenate data and remove duplicates.

```
files = glob.glob('./A08_csv/A08_B1_T*.csv')
dfs = [pd.read_csv(fp,  index_col=[0], parse_dates=[0], dayfirst=True) for fp in files] 
df = pd.concat(dfs)

df_purged = df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True)
print df_purged
```

However df.drop_duplicates(inplace=True) does not work (surely I am missing something) and print returns a void. How can I specify to check the duplicates by index? Adding the column name does not seem to work.

Also, how can I transform this loop into a formula, so I can apply this recursive input to csv with different filenames (i.e something that could work for A08_B1_T*.csv (bedroom) and for A08_KI_T*.csv (kitchen) etc.)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you understand the `inplace = True` option?

If you do it `inplace`, it means you will modify `df`, so don't set the values to `df_purged`.

You here have two solutions: either you want to keep the 'unpurged' dataframe and you do:

```
df_purged = df.drop_duplicates()
```

Either you don't care about keeping it and you do:

```
df.drop_duplicates(inplace = True)
```

First option your result dataframe will be `df_purged`, but in the second it will be `df` which will be purged since you performed it `inplace`.

That being said, if you want to purge on your index, if you don't need to keep it, you can `reset_index` and then `drop_duplicates` like this:

```
df_purged = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(['index']).drop('index',1)
```

And if you need to keep the index (modulo the dropped lines):

```
df_purged = df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(['index']).set_index('index')
del df.index.name
```

(Note that once again deleting the index name is only here for aesthetic)

Answer (score 1):

Would this help?

```
df.drop_duplicates(['col_name'])
```

Here is a solution that adds the index as a dataframe column, drops duplicates on that, then removes the new column:

```
df= df.reset_index().drop_duplicates(subset='Date', 'Time', keep='last').set_index(subset='Date', 'Time')
```

Comment: Surely it would (and I tried it), but the problem is I want the duplicates to be identified based on the index (date and time) and do not know how to use the index instead of 'col_name'.

If I type: `df.drop_duplicates(['Date Time']) ` which is the column name on the csv, then I get a Key Error

Comment: Cmari, thanks for that.
I get `KeyError: 'index'` now.

Comment: CMari, it did not work and returned me `KeyError: 'index'`